# What is the symmetry group $S_3$ asked in this question my professor gave us?

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

We are following the book *Abstract Algebra: An Introduction* by W. *Hungerford* in my Group Theory class and my professor asked this exact question on the quiz:

$S_3 = \langle a, b \mid a^3 = b^2 = 1, bab = a^2\rangle$

a) List the elements of $S_3$

> I know that $S_3$ is the symmetry group of 3, which equals the group of all permutations of the elements in the set ={1,2,3}. But I'm not sure how the cyclic (?) notation is trying to show. I know $S_3$ is not a cyclic group. Is the group we're talking about here a subgroup of *the symmetry group of 3*, or is it a newly defined group? Are they equivalent?

b) List all the subgroups of $S_3$.

c) Give 3 reasons why $S_3$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$

> One of the reasons could be that the cardinalities are not equal, however, since I don't understand what the notation stands for I wasn't able to solve any one of the questions.

I would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: You should use the given definition (a [group presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group)), not your knowledge of the symmetric group.

Comment: The $S_3$ defined is same as permutation group of $3$ elements. It's just given in terms of generators and relations. If you call $(123)$ as $a$ and $(12)$ as $b$:then those equations are satisfied. It's not a cyclic group. A cyclic group is commutative but then $bab = b^2a = a^2$ would mean $I = b^2 = a$

Comment: Not "cyclic notation",  but rather "cycle notation".

Comment: If you have never seen the group presentation notation before, then the quiz question is rather harsh and your first job really is to look up this notation. One way to answer this question is to notice that the presentation defines a semidirect product $\langle a\rangle\rtimes\langle b\rangle=\mathbb{Z}_3\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$ (as $2$ and $3$ are coprime so $a\mapsto a^2$ is an automorphism of $\langle a\rangle$) --- but if you do not know about presentations then it is not clear that this presentation defines a semidirect product. Because nothing is clear if you don't know the notation... :-)

Comment: @user1729 Thank you a lot for your answer, it has clarified a lot of things! Indeed, the problem is that I have never seen the group presentation notation before. I did some research and the problem makes much more sense now. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For c)

1. $S_3$ is nonabelian and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is abelian (most obvious)
2. $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is cyclic and $S_3$ is not
3. $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is (isomorphic to) the direct sum of its two cyclic subgroups and $S_3$ is not

While these may be acceptable for quiz answers, 2. and 3. are so close to 1. that I'd not necessarily consider them distinct answers.  It would be interesting to know what the professor was looking for.